# Windows: Run script upon cd

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, built-in

I've been using a small set of bash scripts to execute various actions upon changing to a directory (say, rebasing repositories, cleaning temps, rotating logs, reading my mail, etc) and noticed this is not a common thing on windows at all.

A cursory google search doesn't show much... is it even something that is possible?

In Bash this is accomplished by writing a small function called cd and having it work on top of the builtin cd. Is that mechanism available on windows? If it isn't, what other alternatives might there be?

Comment: You can do the same thing on Windows by using a batch file such as `cd.cmd`, but you would have to type `cd.cmd` rather than just `cd`. Probably better to name it `cdx` or somesuch so you can just type the name without the extension.

Comment: is there any way I can overlap *my* cd over the original one? That'd be the last piece I need

Comment: Yes, you can invoke the builtin `cd` from within your batch file. The only thing that's tricky is using the same name since Windows will choose the builtin command if you just type `cd`. You might consider asking this question on superuser. Windows is full of nooks and crannies and non-obvious ways of doing things.